# Any good literature about sound design inTerence Malick's "The Thin Red Line" movie?

Tags: sound-design, sound, film-sound-design, cinema

I've just found out that Michel Chion wrote a [whole book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1844570444) about the film ["The Thin Red Line"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Thin_Red_Line_%281998_film%29) and I've just ordered it but in the meantime, I am now looking for something shorter, like a good review or article to convince some friends to (re)watch this movie with a specific attention to sound.

I saw that someone here was writing about it but I can't seem to reach him.
Thanks!

Comment: You are referring  to Chions book about The Thin Red Line, http://www.amazon.com/Thin-Red-Line-Film-Classics/dp/1844570444/ref=asap_bc?ie=UTF8 right?

Comment: @jonhatansmith which book did Michel Chion write about sound design?

Comment: Hi Michael, Hum I couldn't say? I'm more into electronic music. And Michel Chion is more audio about cinema (which is pretty rare btw). One book about [Pierre Henry](http://www.amazon.com/Pierre-Henry-Michel-Chion/dp/2213617570/ref=la_B000AP9Z4C_1_10?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1453880487&sr=1-10&refinements=p_82%3AB000AP9Z4C), also about [electroacoustic music](http://www.amazon.com/Le-Promeneur-%C3%A9coutant-Essais-dacoulogie/dp/2908034964/ref=la_B000AP9Z4C_1_25?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1453880367&sr=1-25&refinements=p_82%3AB000AP9Z4C) could be interesting.

Comment: @jonhatansmith okay - it seems you changed the meaning of the authors text then (perhaps by accident). Michel Chion wrote a book about the film, not about sound design in general. Please take a look at the edit history.

Comment: oops my bad. I'll change that and be carefull in the futur

Answer (score 1):

https://colinatthemovies.wordpress.com/2014/10/25/the-immersive-sound-design-of-terrence-malick/

There's also an article in Mix Magazine from the year the film came out. It used to be up on their website but it's not there anymore. You might look around for back issues.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you go right to the source? Many of the sound crew that worked on that film are still actively working in the industry right here in LA
(see imdb: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120863/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast).

Sadly, the one person you cannot speak with is the Supervising Sound Editor, J. Paul Huntsman, who died a number of years ago.